# Aggregating continuous rows within a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run an aggregate function on the following SQL table to sum up all the "LengthOfRecord" grouped by "Long+Lat" and only rows that are contiguous (i.e. "RowNumber" that is in running sequence).

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| RowNumber | Vessel ID |   Long+Lat    | LengthOfRecord |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| 102313179 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            181 |
| 102313180 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            179 |
| 102313181 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            361 |
| 102313182 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            359 |
| 102313183 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            180 |
| 102313184 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            181 |
| 102313185 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            179 |
| 102313186 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            180 |
| 102313187 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            360 |
| 102313188 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            360 |
| 102313189 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            180 |
| 102313191 | Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |            181 |
| 102313298 | Vessel 01 | 123.750 1.197 |            180 |
| 102313375 | Vessel 01 | 123.742 1.196 |            179 |
| 102313376 | Vessel 01 | 123.742 1.196 |            359 |
| 102313377 | Vessel 01 | 123.742 1.196 |            180 |
| 102313379 | Vessel 01 | 123.742 1.196 |            181 |
| 102313380 | Vessel 01 | 123.742 1.196 |            178 |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

The following is the result that I am trying to achieve through SQL statements. Is there anyway that I can do this through an SQL query?

```
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| Vessel ID |   Long+Lat    | LengthOfRecord |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| Vessel 01 | 123.751 1.196 |           2881 |
| Vessel 01 | 123.750 1.197 |            180 |
| Vessel 01 | 123.742 1.196 |           1077 |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: Your result set is incompatible with what you are saying. You made a simple grouping on LongLat regardless of it being contiguous. Otherwise check lead(), lag() functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a difference in row numbers approach:

```
select vesselId, latLong, sum(lengthOfRecord)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vesselId order by rowNumber) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by vesselId, latlong order by rowNumber) as seqnum_latlong
      from table t
     ) t
group by (seqnum  - seqnum_latlong), latLong, vesselId;
```

The difference of row number approach is a bit tricky to explain.  It identifies adjacent rows with the same values.  If you run the subquery, you will see how the calculation works.

Answer (score 1):

This may be long but hopefully covers your requirements in a relatively readable manner:

```
declare @t table (RowNumber int not null, VesselID varchar(17) not null,
                  LatLong varchar(19),LengthOfRecord int not null)
insert into @t(RowNumber,VesselID,LatLong,LengthOfRecord) values
(102313179,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',181),
(102313180,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',179),
(102313181,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',361),
(102313182,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',359),
(102313183,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',180),
(102313184,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',181),
(102313185,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',179),
(102313186,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',180),
(102313187,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',360),
(102313188,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',360),
(102313189,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',180),
(102313191,'Vessel 01','123.751 1.196',181),
(102313298,'Vessel 01','123.750 1.197',180),
(102313375,'Vessel 01','123.742 1.195',179),
(102313376,'Vessel 01','123.742 1.195',359),
(102313377,'Vessel 01','123.742 1.195',180),
(102313379,'Vessel 01','123.742 1.195',181),
(102313380,'Vessel 01','123.742 1.195',178)

;With ContiguousRN as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VesselID ORDER BY RowNumber) as rn
    from
        @t
), Starts as (
    select
        r1.VesselID,
        r1.rn,
        r1.LatLong,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r1.VesselID ORDER BY r1.rn) as srn
    from
        ContiguousRN r1
            left join
        ContiguousRN r2
            on
                r1.rn = r2.rn + 1 and
                r1.VesselID = r2.VesselID and
                r1.LatLong = r2.LatLong
    where
        r2.rn is null
), Ends as (
    select
        r1.VesselID,
        r1.rn,
        r1.LatLong,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r1.VesselID ORDER BY r1.rn) as srn
    from
        ContiguousRN r1
            left join
        ContiguousRN r2
            on
                r1.rn = r2.rn - 1 and
                r1.VesselID = r2.VesselID and
                r1.LatLong = r2.LatLong
    where
        r2.rn is null
), Sequences as (
    select
        s.VesselID,
        s.LatLong,
        s.rn as StartRow,e.rn as EndRow
    from
        Starts s
            inner join
        Ends e
            on
                s.VesselID = e.VesselID and
                s.srn = e.srn
)
select
    seq.VesselID,
    seq.LatLong,
    (select SUM(LengthOfRecord) from ContiguousRN r
    where r.VesselID = seq.VesselID and
    r.rn between seq.StartRow and seq.EndRow) as LengthOfRecord
from Sequences seq
```

I've changed some of the column names so that I don't have to keep quoting them because they contain spaces or punctuation. I'd also recommend you either store the position in a genuine `geography`-typed column or you store lat and long in separate columns.

So, the above query. The first CTE (ContiguousRN) just arranges for us to have row numbers (`rn`) that don't have gaps, unlike `RowNumber`. The second and third queries locate the rows within the table that are the start and end of each run - basically, locating rows where the immediate preceding or succeeding rows have different `LatLong` values. We also generate a separate series of row numbers for just these rows, so that, in `Sequences`, we can combine each start row with its corresponding end row.

Finally, in the last `select`, we bring this together and we total up all of the rows that sit between each start and end marker.

I've assumed throughout that `VesselID` should be used as some form of partitioning value and that your actual data may contain details for more than one vessel and this process shouldn't mingle the data together. If that's not so, you can remove most of the conditions around `VesselID` in the above.

Results:

```
VesselID          LatLong             LengthOfRecord
----------------- ------------------- --------------
Vessel 01         123.751 1.196       2881
Vessel 01         123.750 1.197       180
Vessel 01         123.742 1.195       1077
```